# How many people actually died in the Battle of New York?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, daredevil-2015

A newspaper in *Daredevil* states that hundreds of people died in the Battle of New York.

> [image: Daredevil newspaper]
>
> Battle of NY: Buildings leveled, hundreds killed in Midtown battle

However, *Captain America: Civil War* states that "only" 74 people died.

*Civil War* is presumably higher canon, but is there any Word of God on this discrepancy?

Comment: Typical tabloid journalism! Sensationalising the facts to sell more papers! :P

Comment: When did Civil War cite the 74 figure? Did someone say it out loud?

Comment: @DCShannon In the scene where Thunderbolt presents the Avengers with the Sokovia Accords, he plays clips of each of the "tragedies". They have a couple of counters.

Comment: @DariM And Thunderbolt was... whom in particular?

Comment: @dasMetzger General "Thunderbolt" Ross, from The Incredible Hulk, is now the Secretary of State (or was it Defense?) by the time of Civil War.

Comment: He's Secretary of State iirc. He's the guy that makes the "You've operated with unlimited power and no supervision. That's something the governments of the world can no longer tolerate." speech

Comment: Wait... so let me get this straight.  A massive alien army *invades New York*, only 74 people die, instead of say for example the entire population of New York 8.5 million people, and as a result 117 countries want the Avengers to be under their thumb?  What a bunch of ungrateful little ...

Comment: Maybe the Bulletin was counting Chitauri deaths too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have no real evidence for what is clearly caused by the now infamous lack of communication between the film side of Marvel Studios and the TV side, but;

It could be that the New York Bulletin is including the deaths of firefighters, police officers, paramedics etc in their statistic, whereas the figures that the Secretary of State (Thaddeus Ross) uses only includes civilian casualties.

This (sort of) makes sense, because in *Captain America: Civil War* the main reason for the invention of the Sokovia Accords is the collateral damage that the Avengers cause. By definition, collateral damage is;

> the incidental killing or wounding of non-combatants or damage to non-combatant property

As such, it makes some kind of sense that a newspaper might use the total loss of life, whereas an ex-military man may only be concerned with the loss of non-combatants in this instance.

Comment: According to the [US Fire Administration](https://www.usfa.fema.gov/data/nfirs/support/nfirsgram_documenting_casualties.html), a 'civilian casualty' is defined as: `Any nonfire department person who is injured or killed as a result of a fire... Civilians include emergency personnel who are not members of the fire department, such as police officers or utility workers.`

Comment: I forget, were there U.S. soldiers participating in the Battle of New York? Because it would make sense if the invaders specifically targeted them.

Comment: @RogueJedi I don't believe so. I seem to remember a line that seemed to imply that the army (I think the phrase used is the National Guard?) weren't yet on scene, just before Captain America lands on a taxi and starts giving the police orders. However, we only really see a small part of the battle itself, so I can't be certain.

Comment: @RogueJedi A police officer mentions that the National Guard are on their way but will take time, and military vehicles (presumably the Guard's) are later shown firing at the Chitauri, indicating they did arrive.